# Modified Grub4dos to have format tool or command

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, format, grub4dos

i want my usb to boot with grub4dos and then  using it to format hdd by just choose the number of menu

with only 3-4 step and done
example

1. boot on usb then grub4dos run
2. choose format or (delete all partition)  menu then  enter
3. ask if you sure or not   and    DONE! (HDD is formated and there is no more partition just "unallocated space")

this is so far that i learn   i have try using many tool but it is take too longs time and some is to complicate to use(my work is mainly on format everything in HDD)

```
chainloader /ODIN/kernel.sys
boot

title reboot
reboot

title halt
halt

title format
format ?
```

i have question that   grub4dos they dont have command to format   how should i put it in?

is there anyways or any tool to put on grub4dos